# downgrade php from 5.3.5 to 5.3.2

Tags: php, centos

I have PHP 5.3.5 running on my dev server. I need to downgrade it to php PHP 5.3.2 to verify some issues. Is there a tutorial to do that .

dev server OS : Cent OS

Comment: What version of CentOS are you running? Did you compile php 5.3.5 yourself or did you install a package?

Comment: Please edit your post to append the release version (`cat /etc/issue`) and the repo list (`yum repolist`)?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP module is only a simple shared lib. You can compile it on your own. Here is explained how to do it: http://www.web-tech-india.com/articles/php/compiling_php_apache/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [phpfarm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpfarm/) to install the second php version on that machine.